# using proftp and mysql user not found. Password is failing

Tags: proftpd

I am trying to get my proftpd working with mysql.
The user is being found in the DB but the password is failing

i create the password with the command

```
/bin/echo -n "password" | openssl dgst -binary -md5 | openssl enc -base64
```

I then paste that password in the db

this is the contents of the log file

```
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: query "SELECT userid, passwd, uid, gid, homedir, shell FROM ftpuser WHERE (userid='me') LIMIT 1"
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: entering  mysql cmd_close
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: connection 'default' count is now 1
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: exiting   mysql cmd_close
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: exiting   mysql cmd_close
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: exiting   mysql cmd_select
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: user UID 48 below SQLMinUserUID 500, using SQLDefaultUID 65533
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: user GID 48 below SQLMinUserGID 500, using SQLDefaultGID 65533
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: user GID 48 below SQLMinUserGID 500, using SQLDefaultGID 65533
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: cache miss for user 'me'
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: user 'me' cached
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: + pwd.pw_name  : me
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: + pwd.pw_uid   : 65533
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: + pwd.pw_uid   : 65533
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: + pwd.pw_gid   : 65533
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: + pwd.pw_shell : /sbin/nologin
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: + pwd.pw_shell : /sbin/nologin
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: <<< cmd_getpwnam
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: >>> cmd_gid2name
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: cache miss for GID '65533'
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: cache miss for GID '65533'
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: : entering        mysql cmd_select
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: entering  mysql cmd_open
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: connection 'default' count is now 2
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: exiting   mysql cmd_open
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: query "SELECT groupname FROM groups WHERE (gid = 65533) LIMIT 1"
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: entering  mysql cmd_close
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: connection 'default' count is now 1
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: exiting   mysql cmd_close
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: exiting   mysql cmd_select
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: <<< cmd_gid2name
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: exiting   mysql cmd_select
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: <<< cmd_gid2name
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: >>> cmd_getgroups
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: cache hit for user 'me'
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: cache miss for GID '65533'
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: cache hit for user 'me'
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: cache miss for GID '65533'
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: : entering        mysql cmd_select
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: entering  mysql cmd_open
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: connection 'default' count is now 2
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: exiting   mysql cmd_open
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: query "SELECT groupname FROM groups WHERE (gid = 65533) LIMIT 1"
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: entering  mysql cmd_close
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: connection 'default' count is now 1
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: exiting   mysql cmd_close
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: exiting   mysql cmd_select
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: exiting   mysql cmd_select
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: entering  mysql cmd_escapestring
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: entering  mysql cmd_open
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: entering  mysql cmd_open
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: connection 'default' count is now 2
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: exiting   mysql cmd_open
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: entering  mysql cmd_close
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: connection 'default' count is now 1
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: exiting   mysql cmd_close
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: connection 'default' count is now 1
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: exiting   mysql cmd_close
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: exiting   mysql cmd_escapestring
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: : entering        mysql cmd_select
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: entering  mysql cmd_open
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: connection 'default' count is now 2
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: exiting   mysql cmd_open
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: query "SELECT groupname, gid, members FROM groups WHERE (members = 'me' OR members LIKE 'me,%' OR members LIKE '%,me' OR members LIKE '%,me,%')"
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: entering  mysql cmd_close
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: connection 'default' count is now 1
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: exiting   mysql cmd_close
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: exiting   mysql cmd_select
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: <<< cmd_getgroups
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: <<< cmd_getgroups
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: >>> cmd_auth
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: entering  mysql cmd_escapestring
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: entering  mysql cmd_escapestring
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: entering  mysql cmd_open
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: connection 'default' count is now 2
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: exiting   mysql cmd_open
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: entering  mysql cmd_close
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: connection 'default' count is now 1
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: exiting   mysql cmd_close
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: connection 'default' count is now 1
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: exiting   mysql cmd_close
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: exiting   mysql cmd_escapestring
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: cache hit for user 'me'
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: cache hit for user 'me'
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: >>> cmd_check
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: checking password using SQLAuthType 'OpenSSL'
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: no digest found in password hash
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: no digest found in password hash
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: 'OpenSSL' SQLAuthType handler reports failure
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: checking password using SQLAuthType 'Crypt'
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: checking password using SQLAuthType 'Crypt'
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: 'Crypt' SQLAuthType handler reports failure
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: <<< cmd_check
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: <<< cmd_auth
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: entering  mysql cmd_exit
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: entering  mysql cmd_close
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: connection 'default' closed
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: connection 'default' count is now 0
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: exiting   mysql cmd_close
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: exiting   mysql cmd_exit
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: exiting   mysql cmd_close
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: exiting   mysql cmd_exit
```

I assume this is the key but not much luck past here

```
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: checking password using SQLAuthType 'OpenSSL'
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: no digest found in password hash
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: no digest found in password hash
mod_sql/4.2.5[13059]: 'OpenSSL' SQLAuthType handler reports failure
```

any help/ideas would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

you need to add to your passwd value the digest format, something like
{md5}X03MO1qnZdYdgyfeuILPmQ==, the {md5} value is missing in your password string

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It works for me and is as described in the proftpd docs.